# Are these parts of speech correct?

Tags: nouns, gerunds, parts-of-speech, determiners

Considering the following sentences:

> 1. Don't listen to those other people.
> 2. You should always use prefixes with your table names.
> 3. I have even started using them in normal writing.
> 4. See how effective it is?
> 5. People can understand your writing better.

I am prefixing these words with abbreviations marking their parts of speech as a demonstration of why prefixes in general are a bad idea, and some of the words are giving me trouble to classify them. (The message is supposed to be an implicit proof of why adding prefixes to table names in a database is terrible. But I'd like to get it right.)

I've also realized that I'm not sure whether it's best to notate the base part of speech or the inflected part of speech it's functioning as, and would appreciate thoughts on that.

For reference, here is my stab at it:

> 1. com-Don't ver-Listen prep-To adj-Those adj-Other nou-People.
> 2. pro-You aux-Should adv-Always ver-Use nou-Prefixes prep-With pro-Your adj-Table nou-Names.
> 3. pro-I aux-Have adv-Even ver-Started ver-Using pro-Them prep-In adj-Normal nou-Writing.
> 4. com-See adv-How adj-Effective pr-It ver-Is?
> 5. nou-People aux-Can ver-Understand pro-Your nou-Writing adv-Better!

(where *com* means *command verb*)

Specifically:

- Are *those* and *other* adjectives or determinatives? Both? Which makes more sense?
- Should I call *table* of *table names* a noun or an adjective, as it is functioning as an adjective but the base word is a noun?
- Are *using* and *writing* gerunds, verbs, or some other part of speech?

I considered differentiating between pronouns and possessive pronouns, but no obvious abbreviation jumped out at me.

This question is closed, and has been replaced by the following three questions:

1. [Adjectives vs. determinatives](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/358245/adjectives-vs-determinatives)
2. [Nouns vs. nouns used as adjectives](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/358211/nouns-vs-nouns-used-as-adjectives)
3. [Verbs vs. gerunds vs. something else](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/358212/verbs-vs-gerunds-vs-something-else)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48317/discussion-on-question-by-erike-are-these-parts-of-speech-correct). **Comments can only be moved to chat once**. Please conduct discussion in the designated chatroom not here. Further discussion here will be deleted.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's much easier to do parts of speech if we don't confuse them with grammatical relations/syntactic functions , and if we don't get distracted by inflections. A verb is still a verb, regardless of which inflected form it is in.

We'll also need to say a bit about what kind of grammar we  subscribe to. The type of grammar that I work with regards pronouns as a subclass of nouns. It also views auxiliary verbs as a type of verb. If you wish to treat pronouns as a separate category, you would need to change the asterisked instances of *noun* to *pronoun*.

Here are the parts of speech:

**Sentence 1**

> - Don't (verb)
> - listen (verb)
> - to (preposition)
> - those (determinative)
> - other (determinative)
> - people (noun)

**Sentence 2**

> - You (*noun)
> - should (verb)
> - always (adverb)
> - use (verb)
> - prefixes (noun)
> - with (preposition)
> - your (*noun)
> - table (noun)
> - names (noun)

**Sentence 3**

> - I (*noun)
> - have (verb)
> - even (adverb)
> - started (verb)
> - using (verb)
> - them (*noun)
> - in (preposition)
> - normal (adjective)
> - writing (noun)

**Sentence 4**

> - See (verb)
> - how (adverb)
> - effective (adjective)
> - it (*noun)
> - is (verb)

**Sentence 5**

> - People (noun)
> - can (verb)
> - understand (verb)
> - your (*noun)
> - writing (noun)
> - better (adverb)

Regarding the different *-ing* forms here, many modern grammars have done away with the distinction between gerunds and participles, because the distinction has always been based on the syntactic function of the words. Many modern grammars use the term *gerund-participle* to cover these *-ing* forms of verbs. However, remember that gerund-participles are still verbs. So in terms of parts of speech, this makes no difference to their category whatsoever.

The word *using* in sentence (3) is indeed a gerund-participle form of the verb. We can tell that it is a verb here because it is taking a Direct Object, the word *them*. Nouns cannot take Direct Objects. Instead their comparable arguments must occur in a preposition phrase after the noun: *the winning of the race*, for example.

The word *writing* in sentences (3) and (5), however, is not a gerund-participle, but a noun. Notice that in sentence (3), it is being attributively modified by the adjective *normal*. If this were an instance of the *verb* "writing" then we would have had to use the adverb *normally* instead:

- *I have even started using them in my normally writing. (ungrammatical)

As can be seen from the example above this is ungrammatical.

Remember that we said at the beginning that we shouldn't confuse parts of speech with syntactic functions. The word *table* in sentence (1) appears in attributive position before the noun *names*. This is a position that we often see adjectives in. However, that does not mean that the noun *table* is an adjective here. Notice that it does not inflect for grade (comparative and superlative forms) and cannot be modified by the adverb *very*:

- *My names are tabler than yours. (ungrammatical)
- *Those tablest names. (ungrammatical)
- *I wrote some very table names. (ungrammatical)

One further case where it is important not to confuse syntactic functions and parts of speech is with regard to the syntactic function of *Determiner* and the part of speech *determinative*. Consider the noun phrase *the boys' dogs*. Here we see the phrase *the boys'* in Determiner function and the noun *dogs* occurring as the Head of the larger noun phrase. However, notice that although the phrase *the boys'* is in Determiner function, it is not a determinative. It is, of course, also a noun phrase with its own complete noun phrase structure. Inside it we see the determinative *the* in Determiner function and the word *boys* as the Head.

Now we can replace the noun phrase *the boys'* here with the genitively inflected pronoun *their* giving us the noun phrase *their dogs*. Notice that unlike the word *the*, *their* is a pronoun, not a determinative. So even though the word *their* has the same ***function*** as a word like *the* in this phrase, it is still a pronoun, and therefore in my type of analysis a noun. For this reason the word *your* in sentences (2) and (5) is a noun despite being in Determiner function.

Hope (verb) that (determinative) is (verb) helpful! (adjective).

---

<sup>**Grammar note**</sup>

<sup>1. Some grammars, such as *The Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language* by Quirk *et al* (1985), use the term *Determinative* for the function and the term *determiner* for the part of speech.</sup>

<sup>2. Some modern grammarians argue that all determinatives and all pronouns are the same part of speech. So writers such as Mariangela Spinillo or Dick Hudson have argued that  determinatives are pronouns. In contrast other grammarians, such as Abney (1987), have argued that all pronouns are determinatives.</sup>

Comment: I don't understand why you would classify "your" in Sentence 2 and 5 as "*noun" instead of determinative. It is as much determinative as "this" or "that". I also would call "that" in your last sentence "demonstrative pronoun" or "determinative pronoun" instead of just "determinative".

Comment: @Rathony Good question. They are genitively inflected nouns in Determiner function. So they're Determiners but not determinatives (in the same way that different types of phrase can be Subjects). The reason for this is clearer if you look at a noun phrase such as "Rathony's witty comment" <--- That has the proper noun "Rathony's" in Determiner function, but *Rathony's* is not a determinative! Then suppose that you replace *Rathony's* with the pronoun *his* --> *is witty comments*. That *his* is a pronoun there, and therefore in my type of grammar a noun!

Comment: @Araucaria: Several comments may be witty, but *I like **his** best*. That's presumably what you're calling a "noun" usage, but since I couldn't have said *I like **your** best* I don't see how this line of argument justifies calling ***your*** a noun. (In short, ***yours*** seems like suspect reasoning! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Same thing goes, whether you substitute *yours* for *Rathony's* as in "I like yours/Rathony's" or you substitute *your* for *Rathony's* as in "I like your/Rathony's book", it's still an N regadless of whether it ends in /s/ or not. These genitive pronouns used to inflect according to whether the next word began with a vowel. Nowadays they inflect according to whether there's a nominal following them.

Comment: I see the logic in your comments here, but I don’t see why you then classify _those_ as determinative, rather than *noun. Surely _this/these_ and _that/those_ are also just pronouns in determiner function (cf. your note 2). The only difference is that these two don’t inflect morphologically for determiner function. I don’t see any logical way of separating pronouns and determinatives that would put _your_ in the former category and _this/that/these/those_ in the latter.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Well, one argument is that *your* "stands in" for a genitively inflected NP, where you could alternatively have a determinative plus genitively inflected common noun in its place. However, you cannot do this with *this* or *those*, for example. Nonetheless, there are writers (as mentioned in my footnotes) who would say that pronouns and determinatives are the same type of word.

Comment: @Araucaria Given that _your_ is overtly inflected for genitive itself, while _this/that/these/those_ aren't kind of makes that a comparison of apples to oranges—the base form _you_ can also not be substituted for a genitively inflected NP. The only difference is that genitival forms of _this/that/these/those_ happen to never be used—if they were, they would function just like _your_.